# re: events and printed "tickets"

Tags: civievent, confirmation

I just made my first events in CiviCRM, and am wondering about whether the purchaser can print a "ticket".

I assume they get a confirmation email which they could print, but is there an option to print a "ticket"?

My events can be found here:
http://www.keysunitedway.org/civicrm/event/info?id=7&reset=1
http://www.keysunitedway.org/civicrm/event/info?id=8&reset=1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Workflow Message for the event receipt template to include a ticket at the bottom. You can style it with html/css to look like you want. In order to have the ticket always be at the bottom of the page, you can use nested tables.

Here is a similar question [(How) can I add a footer fixed to the page of a message template for printing a pdf?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28617/how-can-i-add-a-footer-fixed-to-the-page-of-a-message-template-for-printing-a/28651#28651)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  That's a great suggestion, but above my abilities, so I'll have them print their confirmation email instead.

I appreciate you taking the time to answer!